# Unity PlayableBehaviour preview in Editor mode

Tags: unity-game-engine, timeline

I'm working on a custom track and I trying to preview it in editor mode.

I have not problem over a "Clip" using **ProcessFrame** method, but I can't figure out how to process track when timeline is away from clip (*before or after*).

I can manage it with "empty" clip, but is far as comfortable.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figure it out:

- When the timeline cursor *enter* into a clip for the fist time, the method **OnBehaviourPlay** was called.
- When the timeline cursor *exit* from a clip, the method **OnBehaviourPause** was called